# WIll Google fiber, reach the Northeast, USA,. Still using DSL and FIOS is not available. For Uploading large amount of data what should I do?

Tags: upload, cloud, data-transfer

Google fiber,? Hoping that it will reach the Northeast,  USA,.  Still using DSL for internet in my area and FIOS is not available in my area, and town has no plan on future installations.

I am trying to make use of a cloud server  and currently  with Verizon DSL my upload speeds are terrible.   Not much use, takes all day  to be able to upload.  And I have   multiple storage drives to upload.  I heard  about Google fiber haven't heard much about it. It seems promising and since  Google is behind it maybe it will.  Was wondering if anyone and any unpublished news concerning  these  areas. 
Just uploading takes too long to make use of my server, what should i do?

Comment: What should you do? Well you could start by finding a suitable board to post such a question, because this ain't it.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you read the guidelines thoroughly before posting questions.

Concerning the availability of Google fiber;  Kansas City and Kansas City, MO , are only areas Google fiber is only currently available.  They soon plan to expand to more areas.   Information can be obtained from Google’s fiber official site located here [Google Fiber](https://fiber.google.com/cities/#header=check)
 https://fiber.google.com/cities/#header=check

Concerning uploading  and transfer speeds for a large amount of data to upload. The ultimate solution would be to know of an upload station.  Such an example as what a company called aframe.com [Aframe's Upload Partners](http://aframe.com/upload-partners) uses, it as it has upload partners in its cloud infrastructure.  Or you can send them your data. Not sure about your cloud server but that would be best-case scenario if they had those services in place.

There are multiple useful upload managers that are standalone  and also integrates into Windows Explorer and that will help you keep the uploads from dropping and has also additional speed settings that you can apply to enable significant performance compared to standard uploading by a web browser.

Here are some that might help you.  Most of these  are sympathy FTPs.

[Files Zila](http://filezilla-project.org/) ‘s comes highly recommend.  Great support information and integration.  http://filezilla-project.org/

[FTPGetter](http://www.ftpgetter.com/) allows you to automate ftp and sftp uploads http://www.ftpgetter.com/

[WebCEO](http://www.websiteceo.com/ftp_upload_manager.htm) FTP Upload Manager  http://www.websiteceo.com/ftp_upload_manager.htm

Well, good luck and I hope the FIOS comes to your area soon.